Will we need to collect our check-in bags at Kuala Lumpur and Singapore airports, go through immigration, and recheck them?
We are a group of six travelers flying from India to Bali via Kuala Lumpur and returning to India from Bali via Singapore. Our outbound journey is with AirAsia, and the return is with Scoot. I booked all six tickets directly through the respective airline websites, and each journey is listed under a single booking reference. Our layover in Kuala Lumpur is 2 hours and 10 minutes, and the return layover in Singapore is 3 hours and 10 minutes.
I have the following query:
Will we need to collect our check-in bags at Kuala Lumpur and Singapore airports, go through immigration, and recheck them, or will the bags be automatically transferred to the final destination via the transit airports?
I noticed that both the arrival and departure terminals at the transit airports are the same.
Since the information on self-transfer and/or auto-transfer of baggage isn’t clear on the AirAsia and Scoot websites, I would appreciate your clarification.

While both are low-cost airlines and generally do not do connections (only point-to-pont), they have exceptions, especially in Kuala Lumpur (and Don Mueang and Jakarta) for AirAsia and in Singapore for Scoot.
In the case of AirAsia, if while booking you didn't have a "Self-transfer required" warning, and had instead the "Connection protected by the airline" notice, then it's a real connection, the so-called "FLY-THROUGH" service:

What does FLY-THRU mean?
The process of conveniently transferring from one flight to another without the hassle of going through immigration processing, and of having to collect your baggage when you are taking 2 different flights to get to your final destination and stopping over at a transit station (e.g. KUL is the transit point for a flight from HND-KUL then KUL-PER).
(...)
What are the benefits of FLY-THRU?

Baggage is checked through to the final destination – guests do not need to collect baggage at transit hub and check-in again (...)
Upon arrival from first flight sector, guests will go through the transfer hall
For international to international connecting flights, guests do not need to clear immigration, thus will not be subjected to fulfill visa requirements in Kuala Lumpur or Don Mueang transit hubs (except during extended delays)
Guests will be provided with the second boarding pass at the transfer hall, if it wasn't given at the point of origin
Guests can then go directly into departure hall.


In the case of Scoot, they tells us:

Connecting at Singapore Changi Airport
(...)
Just remain in the transit area. You won’t need to clear arrival immigration and check in again for your connecting flight, so you won’t need a visa to enter Singapore.


My e-ticket does not mention 'self-transfer required' nor 'connection protected by the airline.'
According to AirAsia’s customer support (via Bo chat), 'If you book connecting flights separately (under two different booking numbers within AirAsia) or with other airlines, you are not eligible for Fly-Thru.'
Since my itinerary to Bali via Kuala Lumpur is under a single booking reference, can I assume that it qualifies as a Fly-Thru service?

Asia support clarified via email: if your baggage is checked through to your final destination, you don’t need to collect it or clear immigration at Kuala Lumpur or other transit hubs. Upon arrival, proceed directly to the transfer hall for your connecting flight. The second boarding pass will be issued there if not provided earlier. For international-to-international transits, immigration clearance at KLIA2 or Don Mueang is usually unnecessary unless there’s a significant delay, so visas are generally not required.
